# Vim pandoc red background

Tags: spell-checking, plugin-vim-pandoc

I use vim-pandoc for markdown editing but it adds red backgrounds to almost every words. Is it an spellchecking issue ? how can I disable this ?

[[image: red background[1]]

Comment: `:set nospell`?

Comment: Modify (or change) your colorscheme or terminal settings?

Comment: thanks @Carpetsmoker just `:set nospell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable spell checking with:

```
:set nospell
```

Answer (score 1):

Another options is to add my langage with :

`:set spelllang=fr`

then add unrecognized words with `zg`